# Following a QWidget while moving

Tags: qt, mouseevent, mousemove, qwidget, qmainwindow

I am trying to make a `QWidget` follow another one while this is moving.

In particular, I have a `QMainWindow` with a button. This button shows a `QWidget`, the "*follower*". Now I'd like the *follower* to actually follow the `QMainWindow` when I drag it around.

I've reimplemented `QMainWindow::moveEvent()` that updates the *follower*'s position, but there is a **huge delay** between the movement and the follower. It works, but it looks like something from 1990! I actually can drag the window around and when I stop, the follower will move.

How can I make the *follower* "sticked" on the `QMainWindow`? I'd like it to actually seem glued to the window while I drag it around!

Any hints?

Cheers!

Comment: Try to call `QApplication::processEvents()` just after you set new position for window.

Answer (score 0):

Docs say about moveEvent:

> When the widget receives this event, it is already at the new position.

So maybe better idea is to check periodically (for example with **QTimer**) mainWindow's position and move follower if it changed.

After your comment, another idea is to reimplement:

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
```

with use of custom widget (i.e. new form or use Qt::FramelessWindowHint) without system bar, dragging would be done by reimplemented custom bar, and in this event you would move mainWindow and the follower together.

Comment: Well... that's not very CPU-free! :) A stickiness may be reached, but at high frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly stated in the manual:

> When the widget receives this event, it is already at the new position

So if you wait for `moveEvent` to fire, nothing will happen until you're done dragging your main window.
If you tolerate the sight of your follower window sitting there while its buddy is being dragged around, it will work just fine though.

This circa 1990 feel is no coincidence. The quirky way Windows moves things around the screen is indeed due to legacy strategies dating back from the days when attempting to copy a bitmap on the screen too often was enough to bring a PC to its knees.

The reason why Qt does not provide a more reactive solution out of the box is that the underlying window managers don't agree on the way it's done. I don't know how X11 handles it, but Windows sure does a godawful mess of it. College kid programming, really.

Anyway, seen from the windows procedure, you will receive a [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-entersizemove), then be fed an unknown number of [`WM_MOVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-moving) (you might want to filter these to avoid moving your follower window too often), until you get a `WM_LEAVESIZEMOVE` final notification.
You can overload the convenient [WinEvent](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#winEvent) method to monitor these native messages.
`WM_LEAVESIZEMOVE` is not mandatory, you could wait for the standard Qt `moveEvent` just as well.

I strongly advise against the various hacks you can find on Google. Sneaking a peek into the event queue and detecting, say, a click on a window's system bar, spying on raw mouse events, etc. 
Though you might eventually get that working, at least in simple cases, trying to rewrite little bits of a window manager, especially one as crappy and archaic as  Win32, would be firmly and repeatedly asking for trouble.

At any rate, jumping through all these hoops just to get a minor look and feel improvement is by no means worth the trouble, in my opinion.